# setTex on ViewPager under MVP does not have effect

Tags: android, android-viewpager, textview, mvp

I am developing an app under MVP architecture as well I am using DataBinding. I have a ViewPager and in the first view-page fragment there are a few TexViews

This is my first Fragment, inside the ViewPager, who has the TextViews, note that setText() method just works on my bind() method but does not work outsite of it.

```
public class ViewPagerFragmentMe extends BaseFragment implements ViewPagerFragmentMeView {

    private ViewPagerFragmentMePresenter mPresenter;
    private FragmentViewPagerMeBinding mFragmentBinding;
    private TextView mFollowers;
    private TextView mFollowing;
    private TextView mPost;


        @Override
        protected View getBindView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
            mFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
                    R.layout.fragment_view_pager_me,container,false);
            View view = mFragmentBinding.getRoot();
            bind(mFragmentBinding);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        protected void getPresenter() {
            Log.d(Constans.LOG,"GET PRESENTER CALLED");
            mPresenter = new ViewPagerFragmentMePresenterImpl(this);
            mFollowers.setText("2");//does not work
            startSocialCounterUp(3,mFollowers);
        }

        @Override
        public void startSocialCounterUp(int number, TextView textView) {
            mPresenter.onSetNumberCounterUp(number,textView);
            mFollowers.setText(String.valueOf(number));//does not work
        }

        private void bind(FragmentViewPagerMeBinding binder) {
            mFollowers = binder.textViewPagerFollowersNumber;
            mFollowing = binder.textViewPagerFollowingNumber;
            mPost = binder.textViewPagerPostNumber;
            mFollowers.setText("1");//works
        }
    }
```

This  my BaseFragment

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = getBindView(inflater,container);
        getBindView(inflater, container);
        getPresenter();
        return view;
    }

    protected abstract View getBindView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container);
    protected abstract void getPresenter();
}
```

and finally my MVP view with the fragment related

```
public interface ViewPagerFragmentMeView {
    void startSocialCounterUp(int number, TextView textView);
}
```

Is quite strange. Is not it? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to replace textview variable calls with binder.textViewPagerFollowersNumber?

Comment: Thanks @maxost, tried, but still not working